# What is a safe level of electromagnetic radiation measured in terms of received signal strength indicator (RSSI) e.g. -26 dBm?

Tags: power, electromagnetism, wifi, safety, radiation

We know that the laws of our countries set the regulatory limits of EM radiated power based on the EIRP transmit power of the antennas of devices.

However, the received incident power is more relevant in determining any malevolent effect on a human subject. The received power decreases as the distance from the Wifi transmitter increases.

I have yet to see any studies conducted possibly due to the very unpredictable nature of radiation patterns.

Comment: Is there an EE question lurking around here?

Comment: It is very well hidden ;-) It was hiding under the EM waves ;-) Yes, I am an EE

Comment: Simple: If it's ionising, any amount of radiation is bad. If it's non-ionising, it's entirely harmless unless it's enough (and of the right wavelength) to heat the subject.

Answer (score 5):

Although in principle you're indeed correct that the interference problem occurs at the receiving side, it is far more practical to set limitations on how much power can be transmitted. This can also be measured more easily to check if a product meets the requirements.

How sensitive a receiver is for interference from unwanted transmitters is dependant on several factors including:

- directivity of the receiving antenna
- modulation scheme
- interference rejection capability of the receiver
- spread-spectrum or not

And this is different for every protocol (GSM, UMTS, LTE, Bluetooth, Zigbee, WLAN etc).

Radiation patterns are not that unpredictable, there are software packages (like [CST](https://www.cst.com/Products/CSTMWS)) that can determine these patterns. These use Maxwell's equations.

The unpredictability comes from the environment you're in, walls, floors, objects and people. Basically anything that affects the EM field. So it is difficult to determine beforehand what EM field strength will end up at the receiver.

Also, receivers are designed to be as good as they can be (it would be foolish to make unnecessary compromises). Also a receiver does not cause interference problems, it's the transmitters that cause the problems. That is why the transmitted power is regulated.

Back to the headline: safe RSSI levels. The R in RSSI stands for *Relative*, so I don't think it means very much. If your receiver indicates "-26 dBm" it depends on the circumstances if that is OK ("safe") or not. Is that with a very good and delicately tuned directional antenne or just a simple omnidirectional broadband antenna ? I mean: it could be anything.